# For loop returns last value | python, xlwings

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, xlwings

I have an excel file with multiple sheets with data. 
I would like to copy the data from said sheets into a new sheet, where each each column would be a column from the previous sheet.

I have tried various locations of the variables (inside the loop, outside), different loop constructions (first "in range", "in range" second) to no avail.

I open the book and choose my target sheet:

```py
wb = xw.Book('file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheets['final']
```

I initiate each source sheet, like so:

```py
en = wb.sheets['EN']
cz = wb.sheet['CZ']
et = wb.sheet['ET']
...
```

I have a list of sheets in "langs" which i iterate through to get data from each sheet.

Finally I have my for loop:

```py
for i in range(2,12):
    langs = (cz,et,...,en)
    column = chr(ord('c') + i)
    col_min = column + '1'
    col_max = column + str(row_count)
    col_range = col_min + ':' + col_max
    desc_range = 'S1:' + 'S' + str(wb['EN'].max_row) 
    for x in langs:    
        my_values = x.range(desc_range).options(ndim = 2).value
        wb.sheets['final'].range(col_range).value = my_values
```

Copying the data into different columns works, but I have an issue where my loop will "use" only the last element in the 'langs' - ie. I can see it copying files from 'cz' and others but the final value is one from 'en' - and this happens for every column.
So instead of having columns:
`'CZ' with data from 'CZ'`
`'ET' with data from 'ET'`

Every column is :
`'EN' with data from 'EN'`
I would like to have to each column with data from each sheet, instead of only 'EN'

Comment: I think it is overwriting the values in wb.sheets['final'].range(col_range) as your col_range is same for all the iterations. You need to shift the range at the end of run of the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you Sayandip, I tried your suggestion but unfortunately the issue still persists - I get data only from the 'EN' sheet in different columns.

Comment: Well, the thing is I do not understand what you are doing in the outer for loop, hence I can not code the solution, but I spotted this line, you may find this helpful: `desc_range = 'S1:' + 'S' + str(wb['EN'].max_row)` where you are only feeding the 'EN' column, I am not sure if this is what you tried to do.

Comment: In the outer for loop i get my ```col_range``` by getting the column letter in ```column = chr(ord('c') +i))``` - so I get target columns c,d,e,...
I then build the ```col_range (S1:S_max). ```
While the desc_range is not built for each loop it shouldn't be an issue as it's only getting the max rows from 'EN' (and the number of rows is the same in each sheet). I could hardcode the value but wanted to do it like this for future files.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue.
Instead of creating nested for loops, zipping the range and list in 1 for loop works:

```py
for i,x in zip((range(1,11)),langs):
    column = chr(ord('c') + i)
    col_min = column + '1'
    col_max = column + str(row_count)
    col_range = col_min + ':' + col_max
    desc_range = 'S1:' + 'S' + str(wb['EN'].max_row)   
    my_values = x.range(desc_range).options(ndim = 2).value
    wb.sheets['final'].range(col_range).value = my_values
```